# React : Unable to update array correctly as per objective

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

> Objective :  If the item added by clicking "+" :

1. It needs to check if the order already exists (if yes, then increment the quantity)
2. If not then append that item to the orders list

**fullmenu** contains the list of all items in the following schema :

```
{  _id: 5eef61450bd95e1f5c8f372f ,
  name: "Burger"   ,
  category: "American"  ,
  price: "100"  ,
  isVeg: false,
  qty: 0
}
```

> **ISSUE** : It adds a new object of item even if it already exists in the orders array **instead of just incrementing it's quantity**

The main code logic :

```
    const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
    const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
    const [fullMenu, setFullMenu] = useState();
    const addMore = (e) => {
        let sign = e.target.innerText;
        let id = e.target.id;
        const newOrders = [...orders];
        let order = newOrders.find(each => each.id === id);
        // if the order already exists for the item
        if (order) {
            let _sign = sign === "+" ? 1 : -1;
            // increase or decrease the quantity
            order.qty = (order.qty || 0) + 1 * _sign;
            // remove item from order list if qty = 0
            if(!order.qty){
                setOrders(orders => orders.filter(each => each.id !== id));
                // setTotal(total => total - parseInt(order.price));
                return;
            };
            // save 
            setOrders(newOrders);
            if (sign === "+") setTotal(total => total + parseInt(order.price));
            if (sign === "-") setTotal(total => total - parseInt(order.price));
            return;
        };
        // if item doesn't exist in the order list
        const item = fullMenu.find(each => each._id === id);
        if (sign === "+") {
            order = {
                ...item, qty: 1 
             };
            setOrders(orders => [...orders, order]);
            setTotal(total => total + parseInt(order.price));
        };
    }
```

JSX :

```
<div className="col-sm-4"><span id={each._id} onClick={addMore} category={each.category}>-</span></div>
<div className="col-sm-4"><FormCheckLabel className="qty" >{each.qty}</FormCheckLabel></div>
<div className="col-sm-4"><span id={each._id} onClick={addMore} category={each.category}>+</span></div>
```

Comment: what exactly the error in your code? what is the desired behavior that not happening?

Comment: mentioned the issue above

Comment: just updated the answer pls chk.... also upvoted ur qn as it was clear about the issue description (not sure why there was a downvote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the order using `each._id` not `each.id`

```js
...
let order = newOrders.find(each => each._id === id);
...
```

**Edit:**
Another thing noticed was that you were mutating the state directly

**Refactored code**

```js
const addMore = (e) => {
  let sign = e.target.innerText;
  let id = e.target.id;
  const newOrders = [...orders];
  let orderIndex = newOrders.findIndex((each) => each._id === id); //<---use correct ._id
  if (orderIndex !== -1) {
    let _sign = sign === "+" ? 1 : -1;
    // order.qty = (order.qty || 0) + 1 * _sign; //<----don't mutate like this
    const updatedOrder = {...newOrders[orderIndex]};
    updatedOrder.qty = (updatedOrder.qty || 0) + 1 * _sign;; //<---update state like this

    if (!updatedOrder.qty) {
      setOrders((orders) => orders.filter((each) => each._id !== id)); //<---use correct ._id
      return;
    }
    // save
    newOrders[orderIndex] = updatedOrder;//<----save updated order like this
    setOrders(newOrders);
    if (sign === "+") setTotal((total) => total + parseInt(order.price));
    if (sign === "-") setTotal((total) => total - parseInt(order.price));
    return;
  }
  const item = fullMenu.find((each) => each._id === id);
  if (sign === "+") {
    order = {
      ...item,
      qty: 1,
    };
    setOrders((orders) => [...orders, order]);
    setTotal((total) => total + parseInt(order.price));
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks alot. This worked for me, I'll post the final answer too.

Answer (score 0):

- `let order = newOrders.find(each => each.id === id);` should be `each._id`
- You forgot `else`:

```js
const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
    const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
    const [fullMenu, setFullMenu] = useState();
    const addMore = (e) => {
        let sign = e.target.innerText;
        let id = e.target.id;
        const newOrders = [...orders];
        let order = newOrders.find(each => each.id === id);
        // if the order already exists for the item
        if (order) {
            let _sign = sign === "+" ? 1 : -1;
            // increase or decrease the quantity
            order.qty = (order.qty || 0) + 1 * _sign;
            // remove item from order list if qty = 0
            if(!order.qty){
                setOrders(orders => orders.filter(each => each.id !== id));
                // setTotal(total => total - parseInt(order.price));
                return;
            };
            // save 
            setOrders(newOrders);
            if (sign === "+") setTotal(total => total + parseInt(order.price));
            if (sign === "-") setTotal(total => total - parseInt(order.price));
            return;
        }else{
          // Should be in else block like this
          // if item doesn't exist in the order list
          const item = fullMenu.find(each => each._id === id);
          if (sign === "+") {
            order = {
                ...item, qty: 1 
             };
            setOrders(orders => [...orders, order]);
            setTotal(total => total + parseInt(order.price));
          };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> This finally worked, thanks to @gdh. Made on small tweak:

```
const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
    const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
    const [fullMenu, setFullMenu] = useState();
    const addMore = (e) => {
        let sign = e.target.innerText;
        let id = e.target.id;
        const newOrders = [...orders];
        let orderIndex = newOrders.findIndex(each => each._id === id);
        // if the order already exists for the item
        if (orderIndex !== -1) {
            let _sign = sign === "+" ? 1 : -1;
            // increase or decrease the quantity
            const updatedOrder = {...newOrders[orderIndex]};
            updatedOrder.qty = (updatedOrder.qty || 0) + 1 * _sign;
            // remove item from order list if qty = 0
            if(!updatedOrder.qty){
                setOrders(orders => orders.filter(each => each._id !== id));
                setTotal(total => total - parseInt(updatedOrder.price));
                return;
            };
            // save 
            newOrders[orderIndex] = updatedOrder;
            setOrders(newOrders);
            if (sign === "+") setTotal(total => total + parseInt(updatedOrder.price));
            if (sign === "-") setTotal(total => total - parseInt(updatedOrder.price));
            return;
        };
        // if item doesn't exist in the order list
        const item = fullMenu.find(each => each._id === id);
        if (sign === "+") {
            let order = {
                ...item, qty: 1 
             };
            setOrders(orders => [...orders, order]);
            setTotal(total => total + parseInt(order.price));
        };
    }
```